# Why is git cherry so astonishingly slow?

Tags: git

Given a repository structure of:

```
o-o-o-o-o-<several hundreds of commits>-o-o-C-o-o master
                                           /
                                          c (files moved to a subdirectory)
                                         /
a-a-a-<several tens of commits>-a-a-a-a-A-b-b-b-b tools
```

This is a multi-rooted repository, all the commits on the 'master' line indicated there have the first-parent being on that branch, and likewise, all the commits on 'tools' have their first parents following the tools branch.

The commit 'c' was done to allow the merge commit, 'C', to be trivial, so that the layout matches that of master.

Why does 'git cherry -v master tools take so long?

EDIT:

My local testing were referring to the wrong branch (I used the wrong name), however, it remains that git cherry is astonishingly slow.

Comment: Does it take a long time to output even a single commit, or does each commit just take time to print out? What is "a long time" mean? Minutes? Hours? Days? Are other commands slow? Did you try `git gc`?

Comment: Just tried it with `time git cherry master tools -v`, it reported: 85.84s user 50.82s system 55% cpu 4:05.16 total, so more than 4 minutes. I haven't tried git gc yet...

Comment: When did the `tools` branch fork out from the `master` branch? i.e. How many commits ago?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: About 2 commits ago.

Comment: @nneonneo: Also just tried it after a 'git gc', it was about a minute quicker, so an improvement of 25%, but still very slow.

Comment: It is as if it's still looking at every commit to the left of 'C' and 'A'

Comment: This is a fairly special question. Maybe you'll have more luck on the git mailing list (https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity ). Also, you should probably provide a minimal test repo to replicate the problem.

Comment: @sleske: That's a good suggestion, thanks, I will have to spend time thinking about how to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Arafangion: can you answer the other questions I posed? Does it take a long time to output one commit, or each commit? Are other `git` commands slow?

Comment: @Arafangion: also, if `git gc` helped, you can try really cleaning up the repo with `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --aggressive --prune=now`. This deletes your `reflog`, so make sure you don't need it before running that command.

Comment: @nneonneo: That implies that 'git cherry' is looking at too many changes. :/

Comment: @Arafangion: Not necessarily. I've worked on repos which were slow to just do `git status`, owing to the amount of garbage in the repo (`git` does examine more than just the commit in question, though exactly why it does this is not clear to me). Having garbage can unexpectedly slow even simple commands down.

Comment: @nneonneo: That is a good point, however wouldn't a fast filesystem (HFS, in this case, rather than NTFS via msys), plus a packfile address that? In any case, the gc certainly did result in a 25% improvement.

Comment: Did you try the aggressive cleanup command I posted?

Comment: No because I don't want to loose my reflog, as I do make rather heavy use of it, although I could clone the repository.

Comment: On further reflection, I dont' actually need the reflog, so giving that a go, although I suspect that the '--aggressive' option there is going to be the most significant difference.

Comment: @nneonneo: It took a very, very long time to do the aggressive cleanup (I neglected to time it, but I would estimate about 30 minutes or so).  However, there was no performance difference with the actual cherry operation.

Comment: Wow...big repo. 30 minutes is quite some time. Are there are a lot of (frequently updated) big binary files?

Comment: @nneonneo: Not with the changes more recent than 'C' or 'A'.  No idea about the previous changes that I honestly don't care about, because I do not care about anything older than what I regard as the fork point.

Answer (score 2):

The **`git cherry`** command starts the comparision from the fork-point

`$ git cherry -v tools master`

```
           __*__*__*__*__> <tools>
          /
fork-point
          \__+__+__-__+__+__-__+__> <master>
```

We can avoid this by specifying a **`<limit>`** parameter to `git cherry` as follows

`$ git cherry -v tools master <limit>`

```
           __*__*__*__*__> <tools>
          /
fork-point
          \__*__*__<limit>__-__+__> <master>
```

Now all the commits along the  branch up to and including  are ignored; thus enabling the `git cherry` command to finish faster.

---

#### Why?

Going through the [man page of `git cherry`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html) we can note the following :

> Because git cherry compares the changeset rather than the commit id (sha1), you can use git cherry to find out if a commit you made locally has been applied  under a different commit id. For example, this will happen if you’re feeding patches  via email rather than pushing or pulling commits directly.

Essentially this means that **`git cherry` is NOT simply comparing the hashes of the commit-ids, but the entire changesets/diffs/commits**. This is the main reason for the seemingly large amount of time taken (compared to other similar `git` commands).

Comment: So given that I have only a couple of commits on each branch after the fork point, why is it taking several minutes to complete?

Comment: What is the "size" of the commits? Do they contain a large number of files? Do they have a lot of "diff" ?...

Comment: THe size of the commits are typically small, however the repo itself is about 1 or 2 GB, not including the working directory